# Using localStorage to display message at initial and subsequent visits

Tags: javascript

I'm running the following script after a login page. The below message appears if it is the first time the user has visited the site.

```
<script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">
<script>
   if (!localStorage['done']) {
       localStorage['done'] = 'yes';
       swal({   title: "Getting Started",   text: "Tap 'Select a Task' from the top menu to get started or watch the training video.",   type: "info",   confirmButtonText: "Got It!", animation: "slide-from-top" });
   }
</script>
```

Now, I'd like if it ISN'T their first visit, to display a different message in the popup. Is `else` the way to go, and if so, what is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible. You should have tried it.

```
var isFirstVisit = localStorage.getItem('_firstVisit'); // get the key

if (isFirstVisit) { // returning visitor 

   localStorage.setItem('_firstVisit', true); // set key

   swal('Welcome back');

} else { // first visit

   swal('Welcome');

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried it but didn't put the } before else. I knew I was doing something wrong, just couldn't figure out what. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An `else` should work just fine here

```
<script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">
<script>
   if (!localStorage['done']) {
       localStorage['done'] = 'yes';
       swal({   title: "Getting Started",   text: "Tap 'Select a Task' from the top menu to get started or watch the training video.",   type: "info",   confirmButtonText: "Got It!", animation: "slide-from-top" });
   } else {
     //whatever alert code you want
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getItem()` and `setItem()`

```
if (!localStorage.getItem['done']) { //this will be false for the first visit
       localStorage.setItem['done'] = 'yes'; //now set the value
       swal({   title: "Getting Started",   text: "Tap 'Select a Task' from the top menu to get started or watch the training video.",   type: "info",   confirmButtonText: "Got It!", animation: "slide-from-top" });
   }
```